# disable osgi temp folder

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, bndtools

I have a problem with the temporary folders that are generated when I run "Run OSGi" from the start.bndrun file in eclipse
at each start a folder is generated below:
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\osgi.7569853241152546985.fw
which weigh about 300mb.

OS:Win 10
IDE: Eclipse 2018-09
Tools: Bndtools 4.1.0 REL

start.bndrun

```
-runsystemcapabilities: ${native_capability}
-runfw: org.eclipse.osgi;version='[3.12.50.v20170928-1321,3.12.50.v20170928-1321]'
-runee: JavaSE-1.8
-resolve.effective: active;skip:="osgi.service"
-runsystempackages: sun.misc,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer,com.sun.xml.internal.ws,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.message
-runproperties: \
    osgi.console=,\
    osgi.console.enable.builtin=false,\
    org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation="sun.*,com.sun.*",\
    org.osgi.service.http.port=8081,\

-runvm:-Xss1M, -Xms128M, -Xmx1G

-runbundles: \
    ...
```

the problem is that after a month I find about 70GB occupied on the disk, which I have to delete periodically. is there a way to limit these temporary folders?

Comment: can nobody help me? I tried to use these: org.osgi.framework.storage.clean 
but it does not work

Comment: Since about a month, we face the same problem using Eclipse Equinox, but not on our development machines (Eclipse), but on the customer machines running the software. Any hint to limit the cached data amount would be helpful.

Comment: It is absurd that there is nothing on the net about this problem. :)

Comment: Not an answer but a workaround: We will set up an automated task on Windows using task planner and cleanmgr to do an automated "Disk Cleanup" until there is a real solution to the problem. :)

Comment: After googling for this parameter it sounds promising. Will try it with out next version. You should put this into an answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this way: Into bndrun file: -runstorage: ${user.home}/osgi/data